# Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in

Tags: php

I'm getting an error (posted below) when executing my PHP code:

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in

query result in array

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [content] => Quodsi animae tuae infami cum magna.........
            [format] => html
        )

)
```

This is the PHP Code:

```
$result[]['conent']
```

This data I am using within the loop itself. So how to get value for both content and format.

Comment: If you would var dump the $result like `var_dump($result);`, you would probably see that key is empty string: `$result['']['conent'];`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$arrayVar[]` is effectively the same (give or take) as

```
array_push($arrayVar, 'Add this');
```

So it implies that you're assigning a new value to a new index in `$arrayVar`. The value doesn't exist (yet), so it sure as hell can't be an array, and therefore you can't access a key, which is exactly what you're trying to do:

```
$result[]['content']//<-- accessing 'content' key of a non-existant array value
```

Hence, `$result['']['content']` is probably what you're after

Answer (score 3):

Hello try `$result['']['content']`

Answer (score 1):

LIVE TEST : https://eval.in/85412
I think it would be something like this:

```
   $aar = array ( "" =>array
                (
                    "content" => "Quodsi animae tuae infami cum magna.........",
                    "format" => "html"
                )

        );

        print_r($aar['']['content']);
```